# How to connect to PCs together via Ethernet for file sharing?

Tags: networking, windows-8, windows-10, ethernet, homegroup

I have a PC running Windows 10 and another running Windows 8.1, I' trying to connect them using an Ethernet cable so I can transfer 100 GB from the Windows 10 machine to the Windows 8.1. I've set IPs for both of them,

192.168.1.10 for Windows 10 machine; (also tried 192.168.0.1 and 0.2)
192.168.1.11 for Windows 8.1 machine

The problem is when I try to set up the Homegroup it keeps telling me that I need to change my network location to private.

I have already tried [this](https://tinkertry.com/how-to-change-windows-10-network-type-from-public-to-private) but still it doesn't change network location to private.

Comment: Are you trying to connect them directly or to a router/switch? If directly, you'll need a cross over cable.

Comment: Directly but I thought you can do it without a crossover cable?

Comment: The machines would need to support Auto MDI-X.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use the homegroup for file sharing at all. if you're gonna use this setup only for the File Transfer then you can share a folder in windows 10 or 8 where do you wanna send your files and then Go to its property and then in sharing tab then click share then select the users who can access the share folder in your network. now get back to your destination system and open the run the another pc's ip in the run (Eg:\192.168.0.11) like this this may ask you the user name and password enter the user name and password for the user you have allowed access. this may show up your shared folders.Or else you can do like this too (Eg:\192.168.0.11\D$)this is also ask the user name and password then it will directly land at your D drive. If you're gonna do too many times for a system then you can simply use the FTP too. And you don't have to be in a home group to share files in work network also it is enough